# Django ListView pagination using Form

Tags: django, listview, django-generic-views

I'm trying to pass "form" as context, my code:

```
class BlogSearchView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    paginate_by = 20
    template_name = "base/blog_search.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        qset = super(BlogSearchView, self).get_queryset()
        new_data = self.request.GET.copy()
        form = BlogSearchForm(new_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            search_term = form.cleaned_data['q']#>> how to insert this in template
            if search_term:
                qset = qset.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_term)|
                                   Q(body__icontains=search_term))
            else:
                qset = []
        else:
            form = BlogSearchForm() #>> how to insert this in template
        return qset
```

try using get_context_data but I get errors.

Comment: i'm using self.get_context_data() but not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overide `get_context_data` in your `BlogSearchView`.

Fast solution:

```
class BlogSearchView(ListView):

    def get_queryset():
        ...
        #Your queryset definition
        self.search_term = search_term
        self.form = form
        return qset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_term'] = self.search_term
        context['form'] = self.form
        return context
```

And then you can use `search_term` and `form` in template.

Comment: why not work form = BlogSearchForm(new_data) to convert self.form = BlogSearchForm(new_data)